# How to solve the error CS0012 after upgrading Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, updates, .net-standard

I was using Xamarin.Forms version 2.5.1.527436, and my project was compiling and running perfectly, then I updated it to Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.637273 and my project do not compile any more.

I receive several errors:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'Action' is defined in an assembly that is not
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

[image]

How to solve this errors "CS0012"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are still referencing netstandard 1.x. In that case you have to switch to netstandard 2.0 as this is required since Xamarin.Forms 3.0

You can have a look at the details at https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-3.0/3.0.0/
Especially I recommend to read the "Build Task Dependency Update" section.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what worked was to Install with the visual studio installer the .NET 4.7.1 and update windows system to build 1803.

Comment: @LedMachine: Why was the update of Windows necessary? If the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted answer.